# How to test FormGroupDirective in component?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular7

I've some problems to tests component with `FormGroupDirective` in `viewProviders`.
Can't create mock of `parent` and set empty formGroup.

My component:

```
@Component({
   (...)
   viewProviders: [
      {
        provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective
      }
    ]
  })
export class SomeNestedFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.parent.form;
    this.form.addControl('field', this.createSomeFormGroup());
  }
}
```

Spec:

```
describe('SomeNestedFormComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeNestedFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeNestedFormComponent>;
  let formGroupDirective: Partial<FormGroupDirective>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    formGroupDirective = {
      form: new FormGroup({})
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [SomeNestedFormComponent],
      providers: []
    })
      .overrideComponent(PermissionListComponent, {
        set: {
          viewProviders: [
            {
              provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: formGroupDirective
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeNestedFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This throw: `Error: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. (...)`
Try to handle `FormGroupDirective` as a service with `spyOn`, but it throws `TypeError: this.form.addControl is not a function`

```ts
describe('SomeNestedFormComponent', () => {
  (...)
  let fgdSpy:  jasmine.SpyObj<SomeNestedFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const FGDirectiveSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormGroupDirective', ['form', 'addControl']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      (...)
      providers: [
        {provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: FGDirectiveSpy}
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fgdSpy = TestBed.get(FormGroupDirective);
        (...)
      });
```

Is there any way to test that component?

Comment: any update on this??

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe create a `TestComponent` with `SomeNestedFormComponent` in template will help. But I didn't test that yet.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I managed to fix the problem of injecting a FormGroupDirective.

My componet -

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlContainer, FormControl, FormGroupDirective} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() controlName: string;
  public formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = this.formGroupDirective.form.get(this.controlName) as FormControl;
  }

}
```

The test -

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CheckboxComponent} from './checkbox.component';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroupDirective, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

describe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
  let component: CheckboxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckboxComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    const fb = new FormBuilder()

    const formGroupDirective = new FormGroupDirective([], []);
    formGroupDirective.form = fb.group({
      test: fb.control(null)
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CheckboxComponent],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        FormGroupDirective,
        FormBuilder,
        {provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: formGroupDirective}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckboxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.controlName = 'test';

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I also needed to provide FormGroupDirective directly in test. In some other tests it worked just using the mock form in useValue, not sure what is the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Let me share what i did on this scene.

Created mockFormGroup as like in my parent component and then created mock FormControlDirective as formGroupDirective to be used in useValue providers.

**Finally assign parent component's form to mocked formGroup like below**

```
component.parent.form = mockFormGroup;
```

It is essential to add FormControlDirective in providers to avoid the error **No provider for FormControlDirective**.

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroupDirective, FormControlDirective, FormBuilder, ControlContainer, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let formGroupDirective: FormControlDirective;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [ FormGroupDirective,
        { provide: ControlContainer, useValue: formGroupDirective }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    //mock parent formGroup
    const mockFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    });

    //dummy formgroupDirective to avoid undefined addControl function
    const formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective = new FormGroupDirective([], []);
    
    component.parent.form = mockFormGroup;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

for ng-mocks implementation:

```
 const fgd: FormGroupDirective = new FormGroupDirective([], []);
 fgd.form = new FormGroup({
   // your controls used in this view part
 });

 MockBuilder(YourComponent, YourModule)
  .keep(ReactiveFormsModule)
  .provide(FormGroupDirective)
  .provide({ provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: fgd }) =
  .then(() => {
    fixture = MockRender(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.point.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  })
```

for bare TestBed:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [GeneralComponentContainingModule],
  exports: [GeneralComponent],
})
class HolderModule {}

@Component({
  template: '<form [formGroup]="form"><fb-general /></form>',
  imports: [HolderModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  standalone: true,
})
class HolderComponent {
  public form = clone(postForm);
}

describe('GeneralComponent', () => {
  let component: HolderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HolderComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HolderComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: Backend, useValue: mockBackend},
        {provide: Facade, useValue: mockFacade},
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HolderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => expect(component).toBeTruthy());
});
```

Here we are making test component hierarchy and compiling mocked component, since components, that are using ControlContainer are not fully detachable or independent from tree - their whole compilation and ReactiveFormsModule work heavily depends on what's higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: I am using your exact implementation, but for some reason i still get the "Error: NG01053: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class)." When i am printing the form in the component the form is correctly getting injected. Do you have any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: @turtle there is nothing about exact `formGroupName` directive in the code above. Mind showing your template?

Comment: `<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container formGroupName="formGroupName">
     ...
</ng-container>
</form>`
the component has these viewProviders:
`viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }],`
and sets the form like this:
`private parentForm = inject(FormGroupDirective);
  form: FormGroup = this.parentForm.form;`
The wierd thing is it works without problems in my normal application.

Comment: @turtle `formGroup` directive class name is `FormGroupDirective` and you are trying to test `formGroupName` which is `FormGroupName`. I think for the best case you should provide mocks for both.

Comment: But don't i provide everything required for `FormGroupName` by telling ng mocks to keep `ReactiveFormsModule` in my Test case? As Far as i understand it by providing the form via your method my real component should have a normal form which should work.

Comment: @turtle you are messing actual tree with reachable packages. In actual tree you have outer `formGroup` (hence provide `FormGroupDirective`) and `formGroupName` (which relies on having `FormGroupDirective` in your actual template and hence you should provide `FormGroupName` too)

Comment: @turtle  btw how does that work `<ng-container formGroupName="formGroupName"></ng-container>` or you missed a structural directive? Just try bare TestBed implementation and recreate you template. It would be easier and more natural.